# Trying to use pstricks with xelatex - almost working

Tags: xetex, pstricks

Have fixed the problem – a bit unconventional though.

I re-installed miktex (2.9), but the problem persisted.

I found the executables for ghostscript on my system (they were there before I ever  had MikTex at all).

They are:-
*gswin32.exe and gswin32c.exe*

The “c” suffix version starts up in a cmd window whereas the other starts in a Windows window.

The “fix”  was to overwrite mgs.exe with gswin32c.exe! (I copied mgs.exe to another place as backup first of course)

**xelatex now compiles a pstricks .tex file from Inkscape just fine.**

Just to see what the effect was I also tried gswin32 .exe, but this does not work properly. I does complete the build process but final output is incorrect (although there is some output of sorts!). Also the display “flashes” several times as the .exe starts up a Windows win.  So, `gswin32c.exe` is the one to use if anyone wants to try this.

The only snag is that any output during the compile process (I guess from `xdvipdfmx`) scrolls away too fast to see it and no scroll bars exist to get it back! It would be nice to be able to read that in case of errors. Maybe there is a way to do that?

As to why mgs.exe is corrupt, well this is strange. It’s certainly is not an executable on this Win XP machine, and even a reinstall of Miktex didn’t fix it. So below are  the CRC’s for mgs.exe. Can someone here say if that CRC agrees with what you have, and if it does, does it execute? If so then maybe it’s an XP problem here.

`mgs.exe` crc:-

```
CRC32   4253D43E

MD5 0DB1D59C4B83D64B21AC7ACC2562107C

SHA-1   17F67BCCE81FEC4B44C70AA04DDA6780D85A2AB3
```

Comment: Your file must be corrupted in some way. The .log file asks to install the `labels` package, and mentions things from `koma-script`, although none is mentioned in the code. Copying the relevant code in a new file compiles fine for me. It is enough to load `pst-plot` for the new syntax of `\psaxes`.

Comment: mgs.exe is the internal ghostscript used by miktex. If I call in a command line `E:\test>mgs --help` I get the answer:
`MiKTeX GPL Ghostscript 9.19 (2016-03-23)`. If this fails for you something is really wrong. Try to deinstall and reinstall the miktex-ghostscript-bin package (with the package manager admin).